# Synchronizing Files And Folders from Local Server to Remote Server in Notepad++ .

Tags: synchronization, notepad++

I am trying to find a way by which I can sync my files on my localhost with my host server . So that when I work on my localhost , the files are also uploaded to the server . It can be thought of like a dropbox functionality  . I have been using notepad++ .